# jquery fullcalender: Assigning an array to jquery object

Tags: jquery, fullcalendar

I am working with

http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/

I am facing a little issue. In the script it populates the events in the calender through following code.

```
events: [


            {
                title: 'Community informational meeting',
                start: new Date(y, 4, 25, 9, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false,
                backgroundColor: Theme.colors.red,
            },
            {
                title: 'SPA / SPOC annual meeting',
                start: new Date(y, 7, 16, 9, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: false,
                backgroundColor: Theme.colors.red,
            },
            {
                title: 'SPSS First Day',
                start: new Date(y, 5, 30, 9, 0),
                end: new Date(y, m, d, 14, 0),
                allDay: true,
                backgroundColor: Theme.colors.red,
            }
        ]
```

the problem is the i have an array of events which is called events_array...

when i do the following

```
events: [
         events_array
]
```

It does not display anything. but when I put an index into the events_array

```
events: [
         events_array[0]
]
```

i.e. it starts showing that first event.

Any ideas how can i set it so that it shows all the events which are present in the array?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what I've read here I think you should try setting assigning the events_array directly to the events FullCalendar's events option like this:

```
$('#calendar').fullCalendar({
    events: events_array
});
```

Obviously the selector '#calendar' will vary according to your needs.